# Using mongodb with class-based view django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I try to use class-based view like below

```
class DetailBookVIew(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book/detail_book.html'
```

with model `Book` is a mongodb model, so how can I use that class-based view with mongodb model, because it will cause error like `AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute '_default_manager'`, the `_default_manager` attribute only available for sql model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Django-mongogeneric](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mongogeneric3/0.0.2) to use a **Document** instead of a **Model** in **Generic views**.

Comment: Is there any ways else like extend/custom the model simply to make  things work?

Comment: @Cuongpt , I don't think so. You will have to write a lot of code and that is kind of reinventing the wheel. Anyway, this library is so simple to use.